# Joomla can't send email via SMTP

Tags: emails, smtp

I'm trying to send email from Joomla via SMTP connected to an exchange server via port 25. However it doesn't send the email,

> sh: 1: /usr/sbin/sendmail: not found

But I'm not using sendmail, I'm using SMTP. Does Joomla needs the sendmail installed to send emails even if it's not going to use it?

Answer (score 1):

Your site is going to send mails following your configuration on Global Configuration/ Server/ Mail Settings.

For SMTP, you have to select **Mailer=SMTP** and the rest of the required information, e.g. **SMTP Host**

Comment: That's what I'm doing, I've selected the **Mailer=SMTP** and have set the SMTP host correctly, but still it can't send email and in the error.log file it says `sh: 1: /usr/sbin/sendmail: not found`

Comment: Joomla relays con PHP general configuration. Ask to your hosting suppor

Comment: So you think Joomla relays on sendmail lib to send email, evenvia SMTP? Because I've tested on another server sending via SMTP but with sendmail lib installed, and it was able to send it, but in the the server without sendmail lib it cannot send.